# An iIssue with SQL database attachment via Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, version

**Me**

An SQL newbie

**My tools**

- VS Community 2017 v15.9.3 / C#
- SQL Server 14.0.2002.14
- SSMS 14.0...

**What I want to do**

I have a file, you say mydatabase.mdb, I am trying to create a connection to the database on SQL Server to access to it. 
The database is not actually attached to SQL server, so I try to create my connection and attach it (correct?) using Server Explorer window on VS. I right click on "data connection" then choose "add connection"; in the "add connection dialog" I select the datasource "Database file of Microsoft SQL Server" and I give it the pathname of my file. Finally I hit "Test Connection".

**The problem**

On "Test Connection" I got this message:
*The database 'mydatabase.mdb'cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server support version 852 and earlier.
Could not open new database 'mydatabase.mdb', CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file 'mydatabase.mdb' failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be open or it is located on UNC share*

**My attempts**

I connected the databse to SSMS. When I asked DB version to SSMS, I got: SQL Server 2016 (130). It is not congruent with MS error report. Anyway I changed database version to 2014, then I detached it from server and try again: same result.

Last note: if I create my connection on attached (by SSMS) database, and specifing directly the SQL server (not the file) as datasource, it seems to work. I could use this way, but I'd like to know the cause of the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed VS 2012, but you are using a SQL 2008 instance: Visual studio does not install SQL for you.
SQL Server 2008 databases are version 655. SQL Server 2008 R2 databases are 661. You are trying to attach an 2008 R2 database to an 2008 instance and this is not supported.

You need to upgrade your SQL instance to at least 2008R2 to open the file (but be aware that if you subsequently attach your existing DBs to the new instance, you won't be able to open then in SQL 2008 again either)

Answer (score 0):

Your `SQL Server` version (the server that reported the error) is `2016`, that is, it supports db version `852` and earlier.

The database that you try to attach is of version `869`, this means it was created on `SQL Server 2017`.

You cannot attach it to an earlier version of SQL Server, so you need to upgrade your server to `2017` or install another instance of `SQL Server`, `SQL Server 2017`.

P.S. You CANNOT downgrade database version, i.e. when you said

> I changed database version to 2014

it is not true.
Maybe you just change the `compatibility level` of database, but it's `version` is still `869`.

`Compatibility level` means a version of cardinality estimator to use + some features, it has nothing to do with `database version` that refers to physical file format. `Database version` cannot be downgraded, only upgraded.

P.P.S.

> I connected the databse to SSMS

You cannot "connect database to SSMS", you are connecting to **server**, and the database is also attached to **server**. And if you were able to attach this database to SQL Server, this means you have **SQL Server 2017** already installed.

P.P.P.S. To detect your `SQL Server version` you shopuld execute this code: `select @@version` (from SSMS). It seems that you have at least 2 servers, `2016` and `2017` on your pc. You can verify this by opening `SQL Server Configuration Manager`, or you can use Windows Services to determine how many instances you have and what are their names. Then all you should do is to **use the correct instance**.

Here is the picture of my `SQL Server` instances, you can verify your instances by launching `services.msc` on your pc.

[image]